# Load all variants of a product in Shopware (PHP)

Tags: php, shopware

I am trying to load all variations of a product.

While using google I found this code snippet:

```
class ProductViewSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private EntityRepositoryInterface $productRepository;

    public function __construct(EntityRepositoryInterface $productRepository)
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function getVariantsOfProduct(SalesChannelProductEntity $product, Context $context): EntitySearchResult
    {
        $parentProduct = $product->getParent();
        if ($parentProduct != null) {
            // We need the parent product to find all variants
            $product = $parentProduct;
        }

        $criteria = new Criteria();
        $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('product.parentId',
            $product->getUniqueIdentifier()));

        return $this->productRepository->search($criteria, $context);
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            ProductPageLoadedEvent::class => ['addVariants'],
        ];
    }

    public function addVariants(ProductPageLoadedEvent $pEvent)
    {
        $products = $this->getVariantsOfProduct($product = $pEvent->getPage()->getProduct(), $pEvent->getContext());
        $matchingVariants = $products->getElements();
    }
}
```

But using the code snippet only an empty list is returned, though there are definitely variants to that product. How can I fix this code?

Comment: Should this "'product.parentId'" be "'product.id'" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work like this.

```
<?php

namespace TestPlugin\Subscriber;

use Shopware\Core\Framework\Context;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepositoryInterface;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Criteria;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\EntitySearchResult;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Filter\EqualsFilter;
use Shopware\Storefront\Page\Product\ProductPageLoadedEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class ProductPageLoadedSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private EntityRepositoryInterface $productRepository;

    public function __construct(EntityRepositoryInterface $productRepository)
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            ProductPageLoadedEvent::class => 'addVariants'
        ];
    }

    public function addVariants(ProductPageLoadedEvent $pEvent)
    {
        $product = $pEvent->getPage()->getProduct();

        if (empty($productParentId = $product->getParentId())) { // Main product or has no variants
            return;
        }

        $products = $this->getVariantsOfProduct($productParentId, $pEvent->getContext());
        $matchingVariants = $products->getElements();

        var_dump($matchingVariants);
    }

    public function getVariantsOfProduct(string $productParentId, Context $context): EntitySearchResult
    {
        $criteria = new Criteria();
        $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('parentId', $productParentId));

        return $this->productRepository->search($criteria, $context);
    }
}
```

As far as I know, Shopware always loads a variant, so it is important that you check the ParentId, this provides the main product id, you can use this id to find out all the variants.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I think the following line is wrong:
`$criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('product.parentId', $product->getUniqueIdentifier()));`

It should be:
`$criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('parentId', $product->getId()));`
because you already search with the productRepository, the property is only `parentId`.

Comment: This does not seem to work either